# what does android apkinstaller actually do?

Tags: android, installation, apk

what does android apkinstaller actually do? I know that it will move the .apk file to the /data/app directory, but what else?

Comment: Explaining this is the purpose of the android documentation and source code; SO is for *specific* questions, not general overviews of systems.